# How do you say "as of ..." and "as in ..." in Esperanto?

Tags: word-usage, translation

Examples for ***as of***:

> As of yesterday, I've been married 42 years.
>
> As of the 5th of September I've been speaking Esperanto for seven
>   months.

Examples for ***as in***:

> The last letter is a T, as in "Table".
>
> How do you say *plain*, as in "It's plain to see"?

Comment: Hi, Chris! These are really two different questions, so the “StackExchange thing to do” is to [split them into two posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). It’s not a huge deal, but it’s worth keeping in mind!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the first case you could substitute "since", so I'd use "ekde".
In the second case ("as in"), you could use "kiel en", but it might help to clarify with "kiel en la vorto 'tablo'" or "kiel en la frazo 'oni simple vidas'".

Answer (score 5):

"As of" usually means one of the following: *laŭ informo de, ĝis, ekde, plej precize, kalkulite ĝis/de* ("calculated to/from"), *kalkulite je* ("calculated on"). My suggestions are:

- *Ekde hieraŭ (plej precize), mi estas edzo 42 jarojn.*
- *Kalkulite ĝis la 5-a de septembro, mi parolas Esperante sep monatojn.*

As Benson's answer mentioned, "as in" can be written as *kiel en*.